# Start Editing a TableCell on single click instead of double click

Tags: javafx

I would like to begin editing cells on my TableView on a single click rather than a double click.

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
tableView.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        TablePosition selectedCellPosition = tableView.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell();
        if ( selectedCellPosition != null ) {
            tableView.edit(selectedCellPosition.getRow(), selectedCellPosition.getTableColumn());
        }
    }
});
```

How can I make it so the table cell begins editing on the first click rather than on a double click?

Comment: An event filter on the `TableView` is invoked before the cell selection/focus has been updated (the event hasn't even reached the cells yet). Also, adding the `EventHandler` to the entire `TableView` means clicking _anywhere_ in the control will cause an edit to try and start—even when clicked where there is no cell. Try adding an event handler to each `TableCell` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.  The `Platform.runLater()` was necessary for some reason.

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
    if (newSelection != null) {
        int row = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0).getRow();
        Platform.runLater(() -> tableView.edit(row, columnToEdit));
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `textTagTable` and how did you determine `columnToEdit`?

Comment: "textTagTable" should be "tableView" in the above code. Fixed. 

You can see how I ultimately handled this here on line 73: https://github.com/JoshuaD84/HypnosMusicPlayer/blob/master/src/net/joshuad/hypnos/fxui/EditOnClickCell.java

Comment: In my case the column I wanted to edit was always column 1, so I have that hardcoded.